# Как предотвратить разрыв элемента при печати в google?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

Если используется `flexbox`, то CSS свойство `page-break-inside` не работает в  Chrome.

```
@media print {
  .list-item{
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
 }
}
```

Comment: А что если флексбокс обернуть блоком, и блоку добавить запрет разрыва?

Comment: @kizoso
Если менять вёрстку то работает.

А  page-break-inside работает для svg элементов? Например g?

Comment: Думаю вряд-ли в самом свг получится организовать принудительный разрыв, разве что попробовать с помощью js создать распорку нужного размера. Но изменение ориентации печати может испортить задумку.